# Why would an activity indicator show up properly on iPhone but not on iPad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have my app setup to show this view when it is loading data:

```
self.loadingView = [UIView new];
self.loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

self.loadingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];

[self.view addSubview:self.loadingView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.loadingView];

self.activityIndicator = [UIActivityIndicatorView new];
self.activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray;

self.activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2.0, self.view.frame.size.height / 2.0);

[self.view addSubview:self.activityIndicator];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.activityIndicator];

[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

Then, I remove it from its superview. It works on iPhone. It works on iPad sometimes too, except for when I'm using the same code in a `UISplitViewController`. I've tried various adjustments to centering the views, etc., but can't figure it out. What's going wrong?

Comment: It's not a direct answer, but I've had similar issue with `UIActivityIndicatorView` instances. I ended up almost always using an `MBProgressHUD`, which can be found on GitHub. Great little library. Gives you even more (which is likely what you want anyway).

Comment: BTW why are you calling `-bringSubviewToFront:` after each `-addSubview:`? They are already added as a top views...

Comment: I know that's weird. Really its just an obsessive thing, because this is a loading view, I'm only trying to have it on the screen temporarily before dismissing it.

Answer (score 0):

I've add trouble with activity indicators in the past as well. Make sure you are not calling the `startAnimating` or `stopAnimating` while any animations are taking place. I recommend calling the `startAnimating` selector in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 0):

The line where you set the center of the indicator looks like the source of the problem. `self.view.frame.size` is probably equal to screen size at this point and so when you show that view controller over the whole screen it's ok, but inside a split view controller it's not because indicator is off-bounds. You can check that from Xcode's Debug -> View Debugging -> Capture View Hierarchy (while the app is running).

Try setting activity indicator's center using autolayout and it should work.

Comment: Holy crap is that tool great. Thanks for pointing it out, I've never seen it before. The issue is as you said. I've done everything else in auto layout, but it spills over the sides. Really bizarre. Will keep plugging away looking for the solution though!